# Immutables autogenerated for MongoDB throws "Can't find a codec for class Immutable.."

Tags: java, mongodb, immutables-library

**Problem Description.**

So I have an item that I want to use with MongoDB

```
@Value.Immutable
@Gson.TypeAdapters
@Criteria.Repository
interface Person {
    @Criteria.Id
    String id();

    String fullName();
}
```

And in-order to support pojos, I've created a MongoClient with the following settings:

```
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), pojoCodecRegistry);

        MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .build();
```

However, whenever I try to perform an insert operation, I receive an error whereas bson can't find the codec for the Immutable class.

The code that creates the problem:

```
        MongoCollection<Person> people = db.getCollection("peoples", Person.class).withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
        Person person = ImmutablePerson.builder()
                .id("1")
                .fullName("person")
                .build();

        InsertOneResult result = people.insertOne(shahar);
```

And the error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class with.immutables.ImmutablePerson.

I've tried registering a ClassModel to CodecRegistry for ImmutablePerson as shown below

```
     .register(ClassModel.builder(ImmutablePerson.class).enableDiscriminator(true).build())
```

However, it saves the "instance" instead of the data in it

[image]

**Question**

What needs to be changed so that the simple insert operation works?
Is it possible to do it with immutables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reached a solution that works:

```
@Value.Immutable
@Criteria
@Criteria.Repository
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableUser.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableUser.class)
public interface User {

@Criteria.Id
ObjectId _id();

String firstName();

String lastName();

UserNameAndPassword userNameAndPassword();
```

}

By setting the above annotations, imported from "jackson-core" and immutables "criteria-common", when compiling the code a corresponding repository was created, In this case - "UserRepository", which then can be used to perform CRUD operations.

Example for adding a user:

```
UserRepository users = new UserRepository(mongoManager.getBackend());
users.insert(user); // add
users.users.find(UserCriteria...); // read
users.update(user); // update
users.delete(UserCriteria...); // delete
```

I recommend reading on [immutables-Criteria](https://immutables.github.io/criteria.html), additionally, I've used the examples provided in the following repository [immutables-git-repo](https://github.com/immutables/immutables.git), under criteria->mongo.